# How to reset all variables in a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, reset

I know how to reset the variable manually one by one, but is their anyway I could call the struct function to re-read the menu(): part? Because those variables are already by default. Or do I have to reset them one by one myself?

```
struct menu 
{
    bool update;
    bool enterPressed;
    int scroll;
    int choice;
    int type;

    menu(): update(true), enterPressed(false), scroll(0), choice(0), type(0) {}
} menu;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: @juanchopanza Set them to the values specified in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way with the above code is to copy from a new instance, e.g.:

```
menu blah;
// reset blah to defaults
blah = menu();
```

Comment: In my case, could I just do menu = menu(): ? Because I don't change the the name of the struct.

Comment: You may need `struct menu blah;` etc. because `menu` is also an instance.

Comment: I didn't notice you had an instance named `menu`, but yes the theory is the same. Personally I dislike naming variables the same as their type as I feel it just leads to confusion.

Comment: @JonathanPotter,  I like it because I know what I'm referring to more. We all have our owning opinions:), so just make a struct called menu?

Comment: Can someone show me an example with doing it with the menu instance because it's not working.

Comment: @Bryan That's probably because you decided to hide the name of the class behind the name of an instance.

Comment: Try menu = ::menu(); maybe.

Comment: @Bryan:  Always choose variable names that are different from structure or class names.  They should be different in not only case.  For example `struct Menu_s` and `Menu_s menu;`

Comment: @Bryan: juanchopanze already gave the solution to resolve that ambiguity: `menu = struct menu();` - the second menu names the type.because it's prefixed with `struct`.

Comment: @Valentin: for complex types you would presumably have a copy/move operator that would handle it?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: You shouldn't be using raw pointers anyway. What you're really saying is, bad coding practice leads to bad code. I don't think this is in dispute...

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, this will work:

```
menu m;
// ...
m = {};
```

This will create a temporary `menu` and assign it to `m`.

Comment: The same as for the answer of Jonathan Potter. What if one member was a pointer?

Comment: Then I'd expect the class to either be non copyable or have a copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz If it's an owning pointer, *always* use a smart-pointer class.